# Filter JSON Result against RQL Query String with PHP

Tags: php, json, symfony, filter

I've an Symfony 4 Api Project which has to filter their Result by an RQL String.

Request:

```
localhost/api?q=altProductId=in=(456)
```

The altProductId is not part of database. It is added by the controller.
The Output is a JSONResponse like:

Response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"altProductId": 123},
        {"altProductId": 456},
        {"altProductId": 789}
    ]
}
```

And it should be for the above request:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"altProductId": 456}
    ]
}
```

I've already tried to parse the Query with Graviton\RqlParser, but do not know how to filter the Json Result with this or another way.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you post code of your current filter?

Comment: Hi Simone, as said i could parse the q parameter as an RqlParser. After this i dont know to go on. Therefore there is no filter that i can show.

Comment: How are you generating your JSON responses are you using API Platform?

Comment: I'm using a symfony controller and JsonResponse

Comment: Can you show the related code (also the part that fetches the data)?

Comment: I do not know why this would be relevant? You could get the query parameter with $request->query->get('q') and for this example one could do $string = '{json}' And that would be the full example i could provide.

Comment: Well, I suppose you are extracting the data from somewhere and that is the data you want to filter... The package you mention parses the Rql Query to a MongoDB query, so that's how you can filter the results in such a case, but I am assuming you get your data elsewhere?

Comment: I GET the Date like the above mentioned three altProductIds, then i can convert with json_decode to an array or object. Thats my source.